# Processing.js: no anti-aliasing on P3D?

Tags: javascript, processing.js

Working on a geodesic dome here. It's working fine, but it looks like crap and isn't rendering anything as antialiased.

I thought smoothing was turned on by default in Processing. Can anyone tell where I've gone wrong? Is it because I'm using beginShape()? I can't seem to change the stroke width, either, and alpha fills don't do anything.

https://jsfiddle.net/ophello/cr1ez8ok/

```
int state = 0;
float scale = 100;
float phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2.0;
float radius = sqrt(sq(1) + sq(phi));
ArrayList<Triangle> triangles;

void setup(){
  size(1000, 500, P3D);
  PVector[] vertices = {new PVector(0, 1, phi),
                        new PVector(0, -1, phi),
                        new PVector(0, -1, -phi),
                        new PVector(0, 1, -phi),
                        new PVector(phi, 0, 1),
                        new PVector(-phi, 0, 1),
                        new PVector(-phi, 0, -1),
                        new PVector(phi, 0, -1),
                        new PVector(1, phi, 0),
                        new PVector(-1, phi, 0),
                        new PVector(-1, -phi, 0),
                        new PVector(1, -phi, 0)};
  triangles = new ArrayList<Triangle>(); 
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[8], vertices[9])); 
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[9], vertices[5])); 
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[5], vertices[1])); 
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[4])); 
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], vertices[4], vertices[8]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[1], vertices[5], vertices[10]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[1], vertices[10], vertices[11]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[1], vertices[11], vertices[4]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[3], vertices[7]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[7], vertices[11]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[11], vertices[10]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[10], vertices[6]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], vertices[6], vertices[3]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[3], vertices[6], vertices[9]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[3], vertices[9], vertices[8]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[3], vertices[8], vertices[7]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[4], vertices[11], vertices[7]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[4], vertices[7], vertices[8]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[5], vertices[9], vertices[6]));
  triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[5], vertices[6], vertices[10]));

  for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    ArrayList<Triangle> nextTriangles = new ArrayList<Triangle>();
    for(Triangle t: triangles){
      nextTriangles.addAll(t.divide());
    }
    triangles = nextTriangles;
  }  
}

void draw(){
  //camera(width/2.0, height/2.0, (height/2.0) / tan(PI*30.0 / 180.0), width/2.0, height/2.0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
  background(255);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  rotateX(frameCount * 0.0002);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.0004);
  rotateZ(frameCount * 0.0006);

  for(Triangle t: triangles){
    t.display();

  }
}

class Triangle{

  PVector[] vertices;

  Triangle(PVector v0, PVector v1, PVector v2){
    vertices = new PVector[3];
    vertices[0] = v0;
    vertices[1] = v1;
    vertices[2] = v2;

  }

  void display(){

        stroke(255, 210,0);
        noFill();
        beginShape();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
          vertex(vertices[i].x * scale, vertices[i].y * scale, vertices[i].z * scale);
        }
        endShape(CLOSE);
  }

  ArrayList<Triangle> divide(){
    PVector[] midpoints = new PVector[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      int j = i != 2 ? i + 1: 0;
      PVector m = PVector.lerp(vertices[i], vertices[j], 0.5);
      m.normalize();
      m.mult(radius);
      midpoints[i] = m;
    }
    ArrayList<Triangle> triangles = new ArrayList<Triangle>();

    triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[0], midpoints[0], midpoints[2]));
    triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[1], midpoints[1], midpoints[0]));
    triangles.add(new Triangle(vertices[2], midpoints[2], midpoints[1]));
    triangles.add(new Triangle(midpoints[0], midpoints[1], midpoints[2]));   
    return triangles;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please get into the habit of posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your entire project.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2mL7msm9/1/) is a much simpler example that demonstrates the problem:

```
void setup(){
  size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  line(0, 0, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

It sounds like you're looking for the `hint()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/hint_/), but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2mL7msm9/2/) is a simple example:

```
void setup(){
  hint(ENABLE_OPENGL_4X_SMOOTH);
  size(500, 500, P3D);

}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  line(0, 0, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

If you're still having trouble, please post an updated MCVE in a new question post. Good luck.

Comment: Adding that to my code did nothing but erase the figure. I'm pretty sure there's more to it than that. Try adding that line to the code in the jsfiddle and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @PatrickHennessey Then try other hints. If you still can't get it working, post a [mcve] instead of your whole project. Good luck.